# Entity Framework Core: How to include a null related Entity with its null column properties?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a project which uses EF Core and .Net Core.

I have 2 Entity classes. They are one-to-many relationships. Let say 'Student' N <-----> 1 'Grade'.

```
public class Student{
  public string Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string GradeId {get;set;}
  public Grade grade {get;set;}
}

public class Grade{
  public string Id {get;set;}
  public string StudentGrade {get;set;}
}
```

My LINQ to eager load student like this

```
_dbcontext.Student.Include(s => s.Grade).ToList();
```

Sometimes, I create a "Student" record but I don't set "Grade" for it. As the result, the Grade will be null. Since I use WebAPI for this job, I need to return nested JSON which always includes "Grade" and its properties whether "Grade" is null or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest solution is to initialize property after materialization:

```cs
var students = _dbcontext.Student
    .Include(s => s.Grade)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToList();

Grade emptyGrade = null;
foreach(var s in students)
{
   if (s.Grade == null)
   {
      emptyGrade ??= new Grade();
      s.Grade = emptyGrade;
   }
}
```

Also there is another option with custom projection

```cs
var query = 
   from s in _dbcontext.Student
   select new Student
   {
       Id = s.Id,
       Name = s.Name,
       GradeId = s.GradeId,
       grade = s.grade ?? new Grade()
   };

var students = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Maybe var emptyGrade = new  Grade(); ?

Comment: Or maybe  var emptyGrade = new Grade { StudentGrade ="No Grade"}; ?

Comment: @Sergey Why introduce unnecessary allocations?

Comment: I like this answer. @MTLC, I think a key point with this answer is that shaping the object for JSON isn't really an EF(storage) concern, and can be done after reading in the EF object, which can help keeping layers separate.

Comment: `foreach(var s in students) s.Grade ??= new Grade()` would suffice though.